# Send file from Facebook to Dialog Flow (API.AI): can I get the filename?

Tags: facebook, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am able to use FACEBOOK_MEDIA in event section of an intent (in DialogFlow conversation configuration) and can see the URL in the payload.
Is it possible to obtain the filename somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide filenames for attachments to messages, just [the file type (image, audio, video or file)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages#attachments) and the [URL of the payload](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages#multimedia_payload)